# How do I perform +1 or -1 on a date which I select from previous screen?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I want to add / or subtract a day from a selected date. The user selects for example **09-10-2019**, when user press a button, the date should be **10-10-2019**.

I am not trying to add or reduce a day from Current date.

On the previous screen , I have a variable -> Which is user selected and is not static

> selecteddate = "09.10.2019"

I declared it as a global variable so it can be used in several screens, so in this screen , I get this 'selected date'.

I have 3 **UIButtons**. yesterdaybutton, selecteddatebutton and tomorrowbutton

- When user presses yesterday button then 1 day should be reduced from
  'selecteddate' variable
- When user presses tomorrow button then 1 day should be added to
  'selecteddate' variable.

I followed what the answer said. But unfortunately my selecteddate was a string and I needed to sent string to api in its format.
So , I did the following.

```
let dateFormattera = DateFormatter()
dateFormattera.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
let date = dateFormattera.date(from: datetoday)
let newdate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: +1, to: date!)
let dateFormatterb = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterb.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
let tomorrowdate = dateFormatterb.string(from: newdate!)



let dateFormatterx = DateFormatter()
let day = dateFormatterx.date(from: datetoday)
let newday = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: +1, to: date!)
let dateFormattery = DateFormatter()
dateFormattery.dateFormat = "EEE"
let tomorrowday = dateFormattery.string(from: newdate!)
```

There might be junk code in this, but this made everything work as it should. This gets the DATE and DAY. I had to use this because converting string to date added +1 day to the date (due to UTC timing 18:00) despite doing -1 or +1

Comment: You need to not be working with a string. You need to be working with a `Date` and then everything becomes much easier.

Comment: @Fogmeister I use a pod DateTimePicker ,it returns a string.

Comment: Not according to the code... https://github.com/itsmeichigo/DateTimePicker/blob/master/Source/DateTimePicker.swift It returns a date through the delegate function `dateTimePicker(didSelectDate)`

Comment: @Fogmeister There is some problem using it that way and i had to use this
""""
picker.completionHandler = { date in
            self.BtnDepart.setTitle(picker.selectedDateString, for: .normal) 
""""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use:

`Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: selecteddate)`

This will add one day to `selecteddate`

Then, if you have 2 buttons, as you have explained, you could set a `tag` to each button:

- `yesterdaybutton.tag = -1`
- `tomorrowbutton.tag = 1`

We will use each button's tag to add or reduce days from `selecteddate`

So, both buttons will use this:

```
 @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: sender.tag, to: selecteddate)
    }
```

Comment: This works but somehow using -1 reduces 2 days , I get 08 instead of 09 when I do -1 . / I get 12 instead of 11 when I do +1 . (I think its because of the UTC time? , how can I fix it)?  -> Fixed it by converting the date back to string.

Comment: To change the timeZone you could use 

`YOURDATEFORMATTER.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method like below that  calculates the date.

```
func calculateDate(fromDate date: Date, withUnit value: Int) -> Date? {

    return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: value, to: date)

}
```

**How to use it?**

When yesterday button is selected then you need call method like below...

```
if let date = calculateDate(fromDate: selecteddate, withUnit: -1) {
    print(date)
} else {
   print("date is nil. may be due to different formats of dates")
}
```

When tomorrow button is selected then you need call method like below...

```
if let date = calculateDate(fromDate: selecteddate, withUnit: 1) {
    print(date)
} else {
   print("date is nil. may be due to different formats of dates")
}
```

**Note: Please use date format if required. The date format should be same for all dates.**

Answer (score 1):

You still need to convert your string to a concrete object which in your case is `Date`. To it you can add or subtract components as you wish. In your case those are days alone. Check the following:

```
func addDays(_ days: Int, toDate dateString: String?) throws -> String {

    guard let dateString = dateString else { throw NSError(domain: "Add days", code: 400, userInfo: ["dev_message": "String is null"]) }

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd'.'MM'.'yyyy"
    // formatter.dateFormat = "MM'.'dd'.'yyyy" // Not sure which

    guard let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) else { throw NSError(domain: "Add days", code: 400, userInfo: ["dev_message": "Incorrect date format. Expecting \(formatter.dateFormat!)"]) }

    guard let newDate = formatter.calendar.date(byAdding: {
        var components: DateComponents = DateComponents()
        components.day = days
        return components
    }(), to: date) else { throw NSError(domain: "Add days", code: 400, userInfo: ["dev_message": "Could not add days for some reason"]) }

    return formatter.string(from: newDate)
}
```

A usage I tried was:

```
print(try! addDays(1, toDate: "09.10.2019")) // Prints 10.10.2019
print(try! addDays(30, toDate: "09.10.2019")) // Prints 08.11.2019
print(try! addDays(-1, toDate: "09.10.2019")) // Prints 08.10.2019
```

So in your case you need `addDays(1, toDate: "09.10.2019")`to get to next day and `addDays(-1, toDate: "09.10.2019")` for previous day.